# Assigning different colors to cells depending on which selection a user makes (using core data)

Tags: ios, core-data, colors, cell, uitableview

I have a working app so far which basically consists of the following:

Using Core Data, I have 1 Table View Controller with an Add Button which modally calls up a new View Controller prompting the user to add text into three fields. There is also a selection field where the user has to choose between "bought" and "sold". When the user clicks save, the entry is added to the table view controller as a subtitle cell with the information filled in. It works well right now without the bought and sold aspect.

What I would like to do is simply change the color of the table view cell to be green for sold and red for bought. So when a user goes to add the information, they fill in the required fields and also choose bought or sold and then when clicking save, the table view cell displays either the green or red for each entry.

I am adding the tableView datasource and delegate methods here in the current TableViewController. With this, I am basically looking into a "Transaction" entity and fetching relationships to other Entities. The "Status" (Bought/Sold) is also in a related Entity to the Transaction Entity, in it's own entity called Purchase. So Transaction has a relationship called status.action (action being the inverse attribute to the Transaction).

Here's the code so far from the TableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.transactions.count;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSManagedObject *transaction = [self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"whoBy.name"], [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"gifting.amount"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"occasion.title"]]];

    return cell;        
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.transactions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }

}
```

The code from the Modal that actually goes ahead and allows the user to add the entries text (as well as select the Bought/Sold which is not implemented yet) looks like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];        
    NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *occasionEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *amountType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Gift" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [person setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [occasionEvent setValue:self.occasionTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [amountType setValue:self.amountTextField.text forKey:@"amount"]; 
    [transaction setValue:person forKey:@"whoBy"];
    [transaction setValue:occasionEvent forKey:@"occasion"];
    [transaction setValue:amountType forKey:@"gifting"];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend cut/pasting your tableView delegate code into your original post as it is hard for me (at least) to understand exactly what you're doing.  However, you're probably going to end up getting a reference to the cell (cellForRowAtIndexPath) then setting the color of that cell.  That would be my guess.

Comment: Please post `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` source.

Comment: Dear RegularExpression and Arkadiusz, thanks for your replies. My apologies for not pasting that earlier; I have done that now and edited the original post. I hope this helps and thanks for writing in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this manually, all you need to do is read the state of the cell's object from the core data store and set the background colour appropriately.

I would also recommend using an NSFetchedResultsController as you datasource. It's designed to work well with Core Data and tableviews, and if you set up the delegates properly, it will even respond to changes in the model without any intervention from you.

**edit**

Following on from the comments you've added, I can see what the problem is.

Core Data stores objects not values. So when you try and put values into a core data store you turn them into objects first. And when you get the object out of core data you need to translate it into the value you want.

You can see this in what you are doing yourself when you add objects to your managed object:

```
 [transaction setValue:@(self.wasOptions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) forKey:@"wasReceived"];
```

This expression returns a BOOL

```
self.wasOptions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
```

A BOOl is a value and can't be stored into Core Data, so you turn it into an NSNumber representation with:

```
@(self.wasOptions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
```

So you now have an NSNumber object representing the BOOL value of YES or NO stored in core data.

When you try and get the value for your key:

```
 [transaction valueForKey:@"wasReceived"]
```

This is returning the NSNumber representation **not the BOOL value it represents**

In order to get the actual BOOL, use a convenient method from NSNumber `boolValue`. So to fix your problem replace this expression:

```
 [transaction valueForKey:@"wasReceived"]
```

with this expression:

```
[[transaction valueForKey:@"wasReceived"] boolValue]
```

which returns a proper BOOL value that your conditional can operate on.

Comment: Dear Abizem, thank you very much for your reply and that is very helpful. I've now got the segmented control set up and adding to the Core Data, how exactly would I call this from the cellForRowAtIndexPath? I have the following for the detail text label, but how would I go about calling this key? [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"occasion.title"]]];

Comment: In the cellForRow, I'm putting the following code and only getting green cells for some reason.. regardless of which segment I select.. any thoughts?    NSManagedObject *transaction = [self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([transaction valueForKey:@"wasReceived"])
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
    }

Comment: Log the value of `[transaction valueForKey:@"wasReceived"]` and tell me what it is. I'm particularly interested in whether it shows that it is a BOOL or an NSNumber

Comment: Thanks - I'm not quite sure what values to parse in the NSLog.. I put NSLog(@"value = %@", transaction) and I got an NSLog of every result currently in the table. When I go through that, wasReceived has a value of 0 when I clicked the first option in the UISegmentController and 1 when I clicked the second. I did a breakpoint at the if statement and it actually looks like it skips that.. wasReceived is an attribute on the Transaction Entity and I'm not quite sure how to obtain the log for you to see if it's an NSNumber or BOOL - the ManagedObjectSubclass of Transaction puts it as NSNumber *was.

Comment: Also, my "Save" method in the other View Controller which adds the values to the Entities/Attributes is:
NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[transaction setValue:@(self.wasOptions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) forKey:@"wasReceived"];

is that right?

Comment: Dear Abizern, that worked like a charm with the boolValue. Honestly, it was not just a great answer helping me achieve this task (where now if I select the first segment, it's a green cell when I hit Save and a Red cell if I hit the other segment), it's the fact that you explained it so well. Thanks so much for your time with this issue; it's a massive learning experience for me and I'm glad to take this knowledge forward. Thanks again

Comment: Dear @Abizern, I hope you're well.. I've now implemented the NSFetchedResultsController and it's working really well, but wit the above code and the colors, it doesn't piece together with the boolValue. I'm calling now if (transaction.wasReceived) and it throws up an "expected identifier" error if I put boolValue. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: Actually - don't worry, all sorted! Was attempting if ([transaction.wasReceived] boolValue]) instead of putting the boolValue before the ]. Works now!